# How to reflect python changes in django, uwsgi and nginx setup

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Hi I have deployed Django using UWSGI and Nginx using following tutorial http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html
Everything is running fine. I face a challenge while updating python code. I don't know the efficient way to deploy new changes. 
after hit and trial, I used following commands to deploy

```
git pull; sudo service uwsgi stop; sudo service nginx restart; sudo service uwsgi restart; /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

this command works fine. But I face following problems

1. Usagi runs in the foreground. Every time I make changes, a new UWSGI instance start running.
2. Due to multiple UWSGI instances, My AWS server get crashed, due to memory exhaustion.

I want to know what commands should I run to reflect changes in python code. 
PS: in my previous APACHE Django setup, I only used to restart apache, is it possible to reflect changes by only restarting nginx.

Comment: why do you run uwsgi in foreground?

Comment: How should I run it ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
git pull
python manage.py migrate  # to run any migrations
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

Press Ctrl + Z and then `bg` + enter
This should run the process in the background.

Please let me know if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at this for running uwsgi in background. create an .ini file  /etc/uwsgi/sites/projectname.ini. The script would look like this(for ubuntu 16.04):

```
[uwsgi]
project = projectname
base = projectpath

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 5

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
```

**(For ubuntu 16.04):**

then  create the following systemd script at /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI Emperor service
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
Restart=always
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=notify
StandardError=syslog
NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Refresh the state of the systemd init system with this new uWSGI service on board

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

In order to start the script you'll need to run the following:

```
sudo systemctl start uwsgi
```

In order to start uWSGI on reboot, you will also need:

```
sudo systemctl enable uwsgi
```

You can use the following to check its status:

```
systemctl status uwsgi
```

**(For ubuntu 14.04):**

Create an upstart script for uWSGI:

```
sudo nano /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
```

Then add following lines in the above created file:

```
description "uWSGI application server in Emperor mode"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid user
setgid www-data

exec /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites
```

Comment: on Ubuntu 14.04, it gives following erro. sudo: systemctl: command not found. How to get around with it ?

Comment: I have updated the answer for ubuntu version 14.04. The top most part is common for all the versions and rest part is divided based on version. Please check.

Comment: i already have a similar upstart script, which runs automatically whenever UWSGI is killed, but even after restarting it gives me error at nginx named" 502 Bad Gateway".  this error disappears only when i run this command
`git pull; sudo service uwsgi stop; sudo service nginx restart; sudo service UWSGI restart; /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals`
I want to know how to deploy my changes, without running uwsgi again and again.

Comment: @jugadengg It seems to be working for me. Please refer this link for further details: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04